# multiple mounts of the same iso

Tags: powershell, mount, iso

I have a script that mounts an ISO file does some work and later unmounts the same ISO file.
I'm interested in running multiple instances of this script in parallel on the same machine.

Currently, to mount an ISO file I'm using this PowerShell command:

```
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath C:\ewdk\10.0.20339.0.iso
```

This mounts the ISO file and assigns a drive letter to it.

You can run this command multiple times to mount the same ISO on using different drive letters:

```
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath C:\ewdk\10.0.20339.0.iso
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath C:\ewdk\10.0.20339.0.iso
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath C:\ewdk\10.0.20339.0.iso
Get-Volume
```

Sample output:

```
DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- ------------- ----
C NTFS Fixed Healthy OK 62.98 GB 100 GB
D Unknown CD-ROM Healthy Unknown 0 B 0 B
A Unknown Removable Healthy Unknown 0 B 0 B
F EW_MULFREO_EN-US_DV9 Unknown CD-ROM Healthy OK 0 B 15.72 GB
G EW_MULFREO_EN-US_DV9 Unknown CD-ROM Healthy OK 0 B 15.72 GB
E EW_MULFREO_EN-US_DV9 Unknown CD-ROM Healthy OK 0 B 15.72 GB
```

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to get the letter of the current mount:

```
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath C:\ewdk\10.0.20339.0.iso  -PassThru | Get-Volume
```

Sample output:

```
DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- ------------- ----
E EW_MULFREO_EN-US_DV9 Unknown CD-ROM Healthy OK 0 B 15.72 GB
```

`Get-Volume` always returns the drive with the letter E (the first mount letter), even after multiple mounts.

Is there a way to obtain the letter that `Mount-DiskImage` mounted currently?

Are there other ways/tools that can do something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just reuse any existing mount of the same ISO file, instead of creating a new one?

Comment: reusing means that we have two scripts running in parallel that could be using the same drive, when one script finish its job and dismount the drive, it will interfere with the other script work.

Comment: @eli what's preventing two scripts from using the same drive simultaneous? Mounted ISO's aren't writable, so there's no need for exclusive reads

Comment: and why not just mount directly to an NTFS folder? A drive letter isn't necessary

Comment: @Mathias its about returning the machine we are running the script on to the original state(as much as we can) after the script finished doing its work.
when we have two scripts using the same resources, we need to make some kind of synchronization mechanism that will mount the iso when one of the scripts needs it and dismount it when all scripts done using it.

Comment: @phuclv mount the iso on a folder, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: @eli [check this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2faa6c3-35e8-4bad-8ac8-24902bbb6f1a/what-is-the-point-of-nodriveletter-in-mountdiskimage): `$Image = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath path/to/ISO -NoDriveLetter -PassThru; $Vol = Get-Volume -DiskImage $Image; $Drive = Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter "Label = '$($Vol.FileSystemLabel)'" -ErrorAction Stop; $Drive.AddMountPoint('C:\mount\point')`